# Why value remains borrowed even after its sope ends?

Tags: rust, scope, move-semantics, borrow-checker

I am trying to break a text intro substrings.
However the Rust compiler issues E0505.

Here is a cut down version of the code:

```
struct N<'e> {
    name: &'e str,
}

struct BigState<'e> {
    text: &'e str,
    nm: Option<N<'e>>,
}

fn mod_text<'e>(s: &'e mut &'e str) -> N<'e> {
    let h = s.split_at(3).0;
    *s = s.split_at(3).1;
    return N { name: h };
}

fn print_and_destroy(bs: BigState) {
    println!("{:}", bs.text);
    println!("{:}", bs.nm.unwrap().name);
}

fn main() {
    let text = "12345789";
    let mut bs = BigState {
        text: text,
        nm: None,
    };
    {
        let fresh_nm = mod_text(&mut bs.text);
        bs.nm = Some(fresh_nm);
    }
    print_and_destroy(bs);
}
```

I don't understand why is `bs.text` still borrowed after the function `mod_text` returns.

The expected result whould be:

```
456789
123
```

What has to give so the code will compile?

Comment: It's because you explicitly told the compiler that the borrow should live as long as the borrow of `text`. Changing `&'e mut &'e str` to `&mut &'e str` should fix this. (I think this can be further simplified, but that should fix the immediate problem.)

Comment: Tip: You don't need an explicit `return` in Rust, you can just leave the last value without a trailing `;`, as in `N { ... }` on the last line.

Comment: @SvenMarnach This is exactly what I was looking for, please frame it as an answer and I shall accept it. It was not obvious that the lifetime constraint is only for the borrow and the result.